# Why won't this vertically align? Img to the left of div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm still having trouble with vertical-align, although having used it many times successfully. In this case, I have an img on the left and a div on the right, here's my code:

```css
.review {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.avatarImg {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.reviewBlock {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="review">
  <img class="avatarImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
  <div class="reviewBlock"> <!-- misc elements --> </div>
</div>
```

My img is a few pixels shorter than my reviewBlock, so I would like for it to be shifted down without having to use margin-top. As far as I can see there is a baseline established, see these pictures.
[image][image]

I have tried putting `display:inline-block` on both the img and the div, as well as `vertical-align:middle` and it has not done anything. Can anyone explain what's going on here? Much thanks.

Comment: use vertical-align:middle on the parent div

Comment: I just tried this, to no avail. I have edited my code with the parent div on there now as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;` to both elements will align them.

Make sure you also removed `float`, or else this won't work

As they are `inline-block` I also removed the white space between the 2 by connecting them with a comment `<!-- -->`

```css
.review {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.avatarImg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25%;
}

.reviewBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="review">
  <img class="avatarImg" src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" /><!--
  --><div class="reviewBlock">
    Blaa blaa<br> Blaa blaa<br> Blaa blaa<br> Blaa blaa
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, the float was the culprit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.review {
  display: flex; /* or "inline-flex" / displays flex-items (children) inline */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
}
```

```html
<div class="review">
  <img class="avatarImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
  <div class="reviewBlock">This text is vertically centered.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to put the parent element with display:table and the img element with display:table-cell and vertical-align